# properties are nil in unit test

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I have a class, where I call an async method and assign value from properties, and test the properties in unit test, but my properties turnout to be 0 always, even though the properties has values.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var exchangeRates = [:]
    var currencies = []
    var baseExchangeName = ""
    var exchangeFromName : "USD"
    var exchangeToName = "USD"

func fetchCurrentExchangeRates() {

do some thing//
exchange rates = ...
}
}

unit test

 func testFetchCurrentExchangeRates() {
        let exchangeView = ViewController()
        exchangeView.fetchCurrentExchangeRates()
        print(exchangeView.exchangeRates.allKeys.count)
it returns always 0
        //XCTAssertTrue(exchangeView.exchangeRates.allKeys.count > 0, "passed\(exchangeView.exchangeRates.allKeys.count)")
}
```

can i know how to access values of exchangeView.exchangeRates.allKeys.count

Answer (score 0):

> where I call an async method

You issue could be due to the fact that you are testing the result of an async operation in a synchronous way.

Your `XCTAssertTrue` is executed right after `.fetchCurrentExchangeRates()` is called, but since as you say the method executes an asynchronous operation the assertion is evaluated *before the fetch finishes*, so it reads the initial values.

You can use [`XCTestExpectation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestexpectation) to test asynchronous code.

In your case you could use `expectationForPredicate`:

```
// 1. Setup your expectation
let predicate = NSPredicate { input, _ in
  guard let viewController = input as? ViewController else {
    return false
  }

  return viewController.exchangeRates.allKeys.count > 0
}

self.expectationForPredicate(predicate, evaluatedWithObject: exchangeView, handler: nil)

// 2. Exercise the code under test
exchangeView.fetchCurrentExchangeRates()

// 3. Wait for the expectation to fulfil
self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
```

I'd suggest looking into [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) which is a powerful matcher library with a nicer syntax for async testing.

I'd also recommend to [avoid hitting the network in your unit tests](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/why-hitting-the-network-is-bad-for-your-tests/).